# Error #1046 while importing a database

Tags: php, database, import, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1046

```
Error
--
--Database: "wordpress"
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table "wp_brizy_logs"
--
CREATE TABLE "wp_brizy_logs" (
  "id" bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  "type" text NOT NULL,
  "message" text NOT NULL,
  "context" text NOT NULL,
  "session_id" text NOT NULL,
  "date" datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
#1046 - No database selected
```

Here's my log, what may be the problem?
I'm using XAMPP, but i've tried with MAMP too and the result was the same.

Comment: Simple - you're not connected to a database, maybe a server, but the database itself. For this, try adding your database name at the start, for example; `CREATE TABLE mydatabase.wp_brizy_logs ( ...`

Comment: `#1046 - No database selected` seems pretty clear. (Create/)Select a database first.

Comment: add `USE your_database_name;` before `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: after USE you should GO

Comment: @SamSwift웃 If he/she is creating tables, most likely would be creating more objects or populating the tables. To avoid code complexity, `USE databaseName` is better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an empty table first. Then upload your files into that empty table. You probably solved it by now but just putting this here in case someone else runs into the same problem.